# Item time is off by 2/3 hours

Tags: zabbix

I have two instances of zabbix running on two different RHEL servers. Data presented in web user interface on one are off by 2 hours and on the other by 3 hours (ahead). For example instead of 15:00 it says 17:00. Timezone in /etc/php.ini is set properly to America/Vancouver (the same as settings on my desktop). I use MySQL and database settings  are ok as well. calling 'select now() from dual' test returns correct time.

Comment: which zabbix version is that ? also, maybe better suited for serverfault ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit file: vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix.conf

Update line : php_value date.timezone America/Sao_Paulo

Edit file:  vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Update line: 
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo

Now restart apache. /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

What does typing

```
date
```

return?
Do you have your systems ZONE parameter correctly configured?

My Zabbix installations have both /etc/php.ini and the system's ZONE consistent.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/clock
```

and garantee it's set to:
ZONE="America/Vancouver"

For the host time to reflect the change timezone link the intended zoneinfo file to /etc/localtime,

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Vancouver /etc/localtime
```

Comment: 'date' returns correct time (Tue Mar 15 10:15:45 PDT 2011)
/etc/sysconfig/clock is properly set to ZONE="America/Vancouver" and I created the link as you suggested. Restarted both server and agent. 

Still showing time two hours ahead (15.03.2011 07:35 - 15.03.2011 12:15 (now!)). 

Do I need to restart any other service?

Answer (score 0):

All problems with time in Zabbix are caused by a problem with the client browser, the Zabbix server (Web or Server process) or a combination of the two.  The time of the Database server however does not matter.

Check to see what the host thinks the timezone is.

This link:
[How do I find the current system timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118582/how-do-i-find-the-current-system-timezone)  has more detailed information on how to determine the timezone, but the gist on your RHEL box will be:

ls -l /etc/localtime

If that is a symlink, job done you can now see your timezone.

if not then use the following to determine the timezone.

```
685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb  /etc/localtime
[root@admin ~]# find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f | xargs md5sum | grep 685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb
685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Los_Angeles
685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/US/Pacific
685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
685e6cae6f7d63e690bf35b955ff4afb  /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific
```

PHP (The web frontend) then put's own timezone information on top of everything else.