# How to find current system timezone

Tags: c++, c, linux, timezone

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and set the system timezone "Europe/London".
I want to get system timezone set in above format only not "IST,EST etc.". Is there anyway i can get the timezone string in same format we set like "Europe/London".

As above link is given for duplication but actually it doesn't answer my question. Before posting this question i have checked the above link.

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this out: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html but I'm not sure if there is such a thing.

Comment: See [How do I find the current system timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118582/how-do-i-find-the-current-system-timezone?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for update. I have checked the above link but in the link there is no proper solution i found that'w why i have asked this as second time. Is anyone has any idea than please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.h` defines a function to retrieve the system timezone and save it in two string variables:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char * TZ = getenv("TZ");
    if (TZ)
        printf("TZ: %s\n", TZ);
    tzset();
    printf("Timezone: %s/%s\n", tzname[0], tzname[1]);
    printf("GMT %s%ld\n", timezone >= 0 ? "+" : "", timezone);
    printf("DST %s\n", daylight ? "ON" : "OFF");
}
```

Please note that on some systems (e.g. Linux) this function retrieves it's information from the `TZ` environment variable. If it is not set then an approximation will be given or the variables will remain uninitialised.

On my OS X this info seems to come from somewhere else.

Comment: I ran your program and it gave me this.

amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ ./tz
Timezone: EST/EDT
GMT +18000
DST ON
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ 

Not what the question asked for, I don't think ...

Comment: Yes above program will not give the output that asked for. Output should come in string like "Asia/Calcutta" or "Europe/London".

Answer (score -1):

Why not just cat /etc/timezone?

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ more /etc/timezone
America/New_York
```

Comment: Thanks. As i know /etc/timezone will not exists for all types of linux OS ( Red hat, fedora, cent os, ubuntu etc. ) so i think it is not generic solution.

Comment: Really? Should I remind you that your question reads, "I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and ...".