# C function to get os timezone name

Tags: c, linux, windows, timezone

In one of my application, I get lot of date values from different machines.
I wanted to know the timezone information of those machines.

Is there any C function to fetch that information like below ?

```
-- Asia/Calcutta
--- Africa/Algiers
--- Africa/Addis_Ababa
```

I found functions like `localtime` and `gmttime` which I can use to get the difference between UTC time and local time but is there any way to get the timezone region name ?

Comment: There is no portable and standard C function to get the time-zone. For POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) see [How do I find the current system timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118582/how-do-i-find-the-current-system-timezone)

Comment: Yes!  But it tends to be OS-dependent, sorry.  Visual Studio (ms  windows) uses _get_tzname().   I see dude has provided a competent link to other platforms and ideas.  hth