# Boost - Formatting sub second precision time with a time stamp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I need to get a nicely formatted timestamp (slightly modified ISO 8601) with millisecond precision.

And example date would look like this: `2011-09-28 13:11:15.237-08:00`
The formatting should be able to be overwridden as well.

I've been playing around with [`boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) and [`boost::posix_time::time_facet`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.time_facet) which works just fine except when it comes to timestamps.
Since posix time doesn't contain time zone information this is just not possible (I'm guessing)

So, is there anything else I could use that has millisecond precision that contains timezone information or can I make the `time_facet` work with timezones?

Maybe I should always use UTC?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the boost::local_time::local_date_time class. You can specify a time zone and use the local microsecond clock to initialize it like

```
boost::local_time::local_date_time  my_ldt(boost::local_time::local_microsec_clock::local_time(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("EST-5EDT,M4.1.0,M10.5.0")));
```

You should then be able to use the facets to format to a string.

Edit: Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime  now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    boost::posix_time::ptime  utc = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();

    boost::posix_time::time_duration tz_offset = (now - utc);

    std::stringstream   ss;
    boost::local_time::local_time_facet* output_facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_facet();
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), output_facet));

    output_facet->format("%H:%M:%S");
    ss.str("");
    ss << tz_offset;

    boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr    zone(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone(ss.str().c_str()));
    boost::local_time::local_date_time  ldt = boost::local_time::local_microsec_clock::local_time(zone);
    boost::local_time::local_time_facet* output_facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_facet();
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), output_facet));
    output_facet->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f%Q");
    ss.str("");
    ss << ldt;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; // "2004-02-29 12:34:56.000789-05:00"

    std::cout << "Press return to exit" << std::endl;
    std::string wait_for_line;
    std::getline(std::cin, wait_for_line);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to specify the timezone myself, I want it to be the system timezone

Comment: @Nicklas A: Sorry, missed that. Looking at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136970/get-current-timezone-in-boost) you need to perform some OS specific calls to get the current timezone to then embed into a Boost custom timezone.

Comment: I wonder how effective getting both the universal and local time and comparing them would be.

Comment: @Nicklas A: I've updated my code to show that it is possible, although you only get the current offset rather than a full timezone specification.

Comment: Nice easy solution. I just improved your code with a loop to avoid the case where you have 1 second of difference between now and utc, giving a bias like UTC+01:59:59