# What are the disadvantages to using ctime's tzset?

Tags: c++, c, timezone, ctime, time.h

In a question about getting a system's time zone, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151076/503377) did not get up-voted.

It suggests the use of `tzset()` and some system globals (e.g. `daylight`, `timezone`, and `tzname`) from `time.h`.

After some testing, I was able to get accurate results from this method on both Windows and Mac. But I'm guessing the answer mentioned above was not up-voted for a reason. Is this true? **Should I prefer OS-specific calls instead of this C-standard?**

Comment: `tzset` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Good to know. But is that the only reason not to use it? Obviously Windows and Mac support it and it seems Linux does too.

Comment: As that answer states, `tzset` is a POSIX function (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/tzset.html). It should work on any POSIX compliant system, so it's fairly portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if there is not an standard C function (and you are programming to at least one POSIX compliant system) then you should use prefer POSIX functions over OS specific ones.

If one of your systems is not POSIX compliant, then you should have an OS specific solution only for that system.

Comment: I think they didn't up vote your answer because the question was tagged c++/boost and tzset is an POSIX function. But it would be better to ask there ;)

Comment: Windows is not POSIX-compliant, yet it supports it. What's up with that?