# Get time zone offset from time zone name in C++

Tags: c++, c, time

I need to get time zone offset from a time zone name string expressed exactly like this "Pacific/Auckland". I know that boost::date_time would do the job, but I need to do it without that. Manipulations with TZ variable are also not allowed. Anyone have idea how to accomplish this task in such a way?

Comment: Are you working in Windows?

Comment: You need to find, build, buy, borrow, or steal a database of timezone names. Try the find option first. Perhaps there's one on your linux machine.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: yes, currently doing things in Windows

Comment: @n.m thanks :))) I will try. Actually there is public timezone DB exists for example here https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: @ivan.ukr:- Did you check this: [How to get the current time zone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136970/how-to-get-the-current-time-zone)

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: I need a different time zone, not current. With current time zone everything is very clear.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: Doesn't work for me. Uses either boost or TZ variable manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Howard Hinnant's parser for the Time Zone Database](http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html). He also provides a very good date/time library.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. This may be really what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just had to write the code list the known timezones, so I'm sharing it here.

```
#include <date/tz.h>

const date::tzdb & tzdb = date::get_tzdb();
for (const date::time_zone & tz: tzdb.zones) {
    cout << "TZ: " << tz.name() << endl;
}
```

This uses [Howard Hinnants Date Library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.git), and you'll need to compile in the tz.cpp file and have a path to the includes.

With C++20, the library is part of the standard, but I'm still on C++17.

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed this library.