# How to get the current Boost time zone for Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

This is similar to [How to get the current time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136970/how-to-get-the-current-time-zone)

```
#include <ctime>
tzset();
time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone(tzname[localtime(0)->tm_isdst]));
```

The above code throws '**bad cast**' exception. The time zone from tzname or GetTimeZoneInformation is a string like '**China Standard Time**' which is not accepted by Boost time zone.

Is there an easy way to resolve such a basic problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Howard Hinnant's time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), the following will print out the current [IANA time zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) name on Windows:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::current_zone()->name() << '\n';
}
```

Some [installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation) is required on Windows.  For me the above program outputs:

```
America/New_York
```

The [implementation](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/src/tz.cpp#L3607-L3639) looks up the current Windows time zone using `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`, and then uses [this Unicode mapping](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) to map from the native Windows time zone name to an [IANA time zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) name.